# Are tetrahedron spaceframes strong versus flex?

Tags: structural-engineering

I am considering how a spaceframe would work as a rigid batten in a sail.  Tubes are most often used, so I can't imagine this would be cost effective; it's mostly a thought experiment. I'm not a mathematician in anyway, or even an engineer, just a hobbyist, so if you want to go deep, just know I need a TL;DR at some point. :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sail battens have to be flexible adapt to the angle of the sail and the wind and the configuration the boat captain sets.

Unless one designs an entire boat altogether from scratch.

Comment: I am actually thinking about a junk rig.  Stiffness is important. Many people use aluminum tubes of t6061 alloy.  I'm wondering how would the spaceframe compare to this.

Comment: @TimothyHyer-Devine, usually the trusses and space frames are much stiffer than comparable beams or slabs, at the cost of loss of ductility!

Comment: I think that answers the question for me,  unless the added stiffness exceeded the ductility of a compatible tube, the added work would negate any usefulness